# Use C++ DLL from Java with JNA

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I try to use a DLL from C++  with JNA to communicate with a Fanuc numeric control, from a Java program but always get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

The specific C++ method that I tried to use is this https://www.inventcom.net/fanuc-focas-library/handle/cnc_allclibhndl3

```
FWLIBAPI short WINAPI cnc_allclibhndl3(const char *ipaddr, unsigned short port, long timeout, unsigned short *FlibHndl);
```

And in the declaration in Java I use this:

```
short cnc_allclibhndl3(String ipaddr, short port, NativeLong timeout, short FlibHndl);
```

I tried with different type mappings but always get the same error.

Can you tell me if this declaration is correct?

This is my last program:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class JnaFanuc {

    public interface Fwlib32 extends Library {
        short cnc_allclibhndl3(String ipaddr, short port, long timeout, short FlibHndl);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short p = 0;
        int handle = 0;
        short ret;

        Fwlib32 fwl = (Fwlib32) Native.load("Fwlib32", Fwlib32.class);

        ret = fwl.cnc_allclibhndl3("192.168.1.100", (short)8193, 10, p);

        System.out.println("cnc_allclibhndl3 Ret: " + ret);
        System.out.println("hndl: " + handle);
    }
}
```

EDIT AFTER Daniel Widdis RESPONSE.

Hello, I tried your solution and for the first time I work. The application responds with "ret = -16" which means "EW_SOCKET (-16) Socket error". It is normal, for not having any CNC on the other side.
The problem appears when I connect a real CNC with real IP, then appears the same error that the first time.

This is my actual code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.ShortByReference;

public class TestJNA {

    public interface Fwlib32 extends Library {
        Fwlib32 INSTANCE = (Fwlib32) Native.load("Fwlib32", Fwlib32.class);
        short cnc_allclibhndl3(String ipaddr, short port, long timeout, ShortByReference FlibHndl);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShortByReference handle = new ShortByReference((short)0);

        short ret = 0;

        Fwlib32 fwl = Fwlib32.INSTANCE;
        ret = fwl.cnc_allclibhndl3("192.168.1.100", (short) 8193, 4, handle);

        System.out.println("cnc_allclibhndl3 Ret: " + ret);
        System.out.println("hndl: " + handle.getValue());
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:422)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.cnc_allclibhndl3(Unknown Source)
at testjna.TestJNA.main(TestJNA.java:38)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument in the `cnc_allclibhndl3()` function is a pointer to a `short`:

```
unsigned short *FlibHndl
```

So the proper mapping of that should be a [`ShortByReference`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.5.0/com/sun/jna/ptr/ShortByReference.html).  That will initialize a pointer to a `short` elsewhere in memory.  Currently you're passing a null (0) pointer and asking the native method to access that memory!

Also, you need the C `long` variable mapped to `NativeLong` in Java rather than `long`.  Java long is always 64 bit, but C `long` varies based on OS and bitness.  In Windows, that's actually always 32-bit so if your code is Windows-only you could even use `int`, but in general/cross-platform you should be using `NativeLong` for that mapping.

Additionally the convention is for the `Native.load()` call to be in the interface as a static `INSTANCE` variable, rather than defining it inline as you've done.

Try this:

```
public class JnaFanuc {

    public interface Fwlib32 extends Library {
        Fwlib32 INSTANCE = (Fwlib32) Native.load("Fwlib32", Fwlib32.class);

        short cnc_allclibhndl3(String ipaddr, short port, NativeLong timeout, short FlibHndl);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShortByReference handle = new ShortByReference();
        short ret;
        String ip = "192.168.1.100";
        short port = (short) 8193;
        NativeLong timeout = new NativeLong(10);
        Fwlib32 fwl = Fwlib32.INSTANCE;

        ret = fwl.cnc_allclibhndl3(ip, port, timeout, handle);

        System.out.println("cnc_allclibhndl3 Ret: " + ret);
        System.out.println("hndl: " + handle.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I continue with the problem. Can you help me? (Ask edited).

Comment: Which line number is 38 in your program?

Comment: Is it possible you're using a 32-bit DLL on a 64-bit system?  I can't see anything wrong with the mappings...

Comment: This is a cleaned code. I deleted some trivial lines. line 38 its the call to cnc_allclibhndl3. I have another program in C# using the same library "Fwlib32.dll" an the same CNC and works perfectly.

Comment: Oh!  I just realized, you have the C `long` variable mapped to `long` in Java.  Java `long` is always 64 bit, but C `long` varies based on OS and bitness.  You should be using `NativeLong` for that mapping (in general).  In Windows, that's actually always 32-bit so if your code is Windows-only you could even use `int`.

Comment: That's the solution. (Change long to NativeLong). Now works. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Is the FlibHndl parameter type of the cnc_allclibhndl3 method in the Fwlib32 interface incorrect? I mean that the type is declared as short, and when called in Main, the ShortByReference type is used.

Comment: @XelaNimed `short *` is a pointer to a short.  So it's a pointer-sized variable, pointing to 2 bytes of allocated memory.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but there is a compile time error: The method cnc_allclibhndl3(String, short, NativeLong, short) in the type Fwlib64 is not applicable for the arguments (String, short, NativeLong, ShortByReference) - that is, the same types must be used.